# Can I index system.namespaces in MongoDB?

Tags: indexing, mongodb

I want to be able to do fast prefix searches over system.namespaces in my database which will have a huge number of collections. Is it okay to index system.namespaces? The Mongo docs seem to vaguely suggest not messing with system.namespaces.

Update: I am doing the search directly, a call like

```
db.system.namespaces.find({"name":/^some_prefix/})
```

Answer (score 0):

So first, if you're planning to run lots of collections, ensure that you've expanded the size of your [namespaces file](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections).

> Is it okay to index system.namespaces?

This collection is actually hidden by default. It exists, but it won't appear when you use a `show collections` or equivalent. It sounds like you want to optimize the collection for queries on collection names, but I'm not 100% sure this is actually the mechanism used.

The data in the `.ns` files contain data about each collection and I'd expect that this data is basically held in memory. So I'm not sure that optimizing `system.namespaces` will do anything unless you can confirm that it's actually being used on your specific queries.

The exact answer to this question is probably known by about 5 people and they all work at 10gen :) Your best bet for a precise answer is to check the Google Groups or the code itself. The 10gen staff monitor the groups and you may get the actual authors to answer your question.

Comment: I am doing a query right on system.namespaces, a prefix query like  db.system.namespaces.find("name":/^foo/).

Comment: Ha, well, no guarantees on how it behaves. Right now the only "docs" are going to be the source code or the groups: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user